# Need help determining part of speech for word in a sentence

Tags: parts-of-speech

> By blaring music at home, you will see that the neighbors will become annoyed.

What part of speech is blaring?

Comment: It's a verb....

Comment: Transitive use of ***to blare*** is relatively uncommon in *any* context today. For this and other reasons, the cited example is not idiomatic English.

Comment: FumbleFingers, would you accept *blaring out…*, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin You should put @ before a handle to send a notification.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Your comment surprises me; the quoted sentence is bizarre, but I wouldn't blink at, say, "He was a terrible neighbor, blaring his music at all hours of the night."

Comment: @ruakh: I think [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+music+blaring%2Cblaring+the+music&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20music%20blaring%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cblaring%20the%20music%3B%2Cc0) illustrates my point. It's much more normal to use ***blare*** intransitively (or "adjectivally"), so as my chart there shows, ***the music blaring*** (adjectival clause) is far more common than ***blaring the music*** (transitive verb + direct object). In your example I'd complain about *the neighbour's music blaring at all hours*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree that intransitive "blare" is far more common than transitive, but that doesn't make the latter unidiomatic. Would you consider "empowering the citizens" unidiomatic? https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blaring+the+music%2Cempowering+the+citizens&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cblaring%20the%20music%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cempowering%20the%20citizens%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @ruakh: Perhaps we have different ideas about what "unidiomatic" means. I certainly don't claim OP's cited usage is "incorrect" or "ungrammatical". Searching Google Books for [the music blaring](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+music+blaring%22) and [blaring the music](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22blaring+the+music%22) gives a claimed 8840 and 1350 hits respectively, but that seriously underestimates the ratio because it's mainly based on just the combination of words, not necessarily in order. Scrolling through, the transitive version actually has just 40 hits.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: But that's an arbitrary comparison. It's 100% normal for a word to have multiple uses (with either different meanings or different grammars), some of which are more common than others. That doesn't mean that any of those uses are unidiomatic.

Comment: @ruakh: What can I say? I think I've shown that transitive ***to blare [music, etc.]*** is extremely uncommon relative to intransitive usages such as ***the music blared***. I accept the former is "valid" English, but because it's so uncommon it sounds far less "natural" to me than the alternative. For what it's worth, I don't feel the same way about the near-synonymous *He **blasted** his music out at all hours*. I'll also note that looking at OP's example *as a whole*, I'd still be willing to make a substantial bet it's from a non-native speaker. Which in my book means "unidiomatic".